# Error: The method 'ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

**I'm a beginner in Flutter & stuck with this, PLEASE HELP.**

**The errors are as mentioned below**

Plugin project :firebase_core_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.

Plugin project :firebase_auth_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.

Plugin project :cloud_firestore_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.

/C:/Flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-2.0.1+1/lib/src/provider.dart:179:19: Error: The method 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
-'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart'
('/C:/Flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType'.
? **context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(type) as _Provider**

```
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

/C:/Flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-2.0.1+1/lib/src/provider.dart:180:19: Error: The method 'ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
-'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart'
('/C:/Flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType'.
: **context.ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType(type)?.widget**
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

**Or Please tell me what to write in place of Line 179,180 in this image below**
[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGPXD.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

go to android folder update your buildgradle file like this :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Then Go to Android->App->src->build gradle
check Apply plugin is there or not .

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

   def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }

   android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.asd.emediadesk"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

   signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Thank You for your time, I did what you told, but it didn't worked, but I'm even more concerned about this error : 'ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext', because this problem has occured in my different project as well.
Please check the image I have attached at the end.

Comment: In the main.dart check you haves assigned provider and material app properly?